# Subtracting a particular columns particular content from another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas.I have a dataframe as shown below.I need to substract "VBIAS_5DUT_BOARD[V]" colums item number three(that is 38.74) from all the content of next column( VBIAS_INTERFACE_BOARD[V])

```
Device_ID   Die_Version Temp(deg)   Supply[V]   VBIAS_5DUT_BOARD[V] VBIAS_INTERFACE_BOARD[V]
MAIN_001    0x81        25             1.6          38.77           38.86
MAIN_002    0x81        25             1.6          38.66           38.75
MAIN_003    0x81        25             1.6          38.74           38.82
MAIN_004    0x81        25             1.6          38.35           38.41
MAIN_005    0x81        25             1.6          38.26           38.33
```

May I know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows (N.B. the *third* item in a col will have *index* 2):

```
df['Item_Three_Diff'] = df['VBIAS_INTERFACE_BOARD[V]']-df['VBIAS_5DUT_BOARD[V]'][2]
df['Item_Three_Diff']

0    0.12
1    0.01
2    0.08
3   -0.33
4   -0.41
Name: Item_Three_Diff, dtype: float64
```